# Cannot start Tomcat Server in IntelliJ java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-ee-8, jpa

I tried to restore my project. It was in Eclipse and it worked there perfectly. Now i moved it to intelliJ, It's a JavaEE maven project.
But, when i try to start Tomcat i get an error. It's in the Tomcat log:

```
26-Jul-2020 23:06:16.918 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart Exception starting filter [controller.frontend.CommonFilter]
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/persistence/Persistence
        at dao.JpaDAO.<clinit>(JpaDAO.java:18)
        at controller.frontend.CommonFilter.<init>(CommonFilter.java:25)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:249)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:102)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4528)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5165)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:705)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1727)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:456)
        at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:405)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:288)
        at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
        at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
        at com.sun.jmx.remote.security.MBeanServerAccessController.invoke(MBeanServerAccessController.java:468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1408)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:357)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:573)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:834)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:688)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:687)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
        ... 56 more
```

And this is in the terminal:

```
 Connected to server
    [2020-07-26 11:06:16,480] Artifact BookStoreWebsite:war exploded: Artifact is being deployed, please wait...
    26-Jul-2020 23:06:16.918 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
    26-Jul-2020 23:06:16.918 SEVERE [RMI TCP Connection(3)-127.0.0.1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/BookStoreWebsite_war_exploded] startup failed due to previous errors
    [2020-07-26 11:06:16,949] Artifact BookStoreWebsite:war exploded: Error during artifact deployment. See server log for details.
    26-Jul-2020 23:06:26.299 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory РЈСЃС‚Р°РЅРѕРІРєР° РІРµР± РїСЂРёР»РѕР¶РµРЅРёСЏ РІ РїР°РїРєСѓ [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager]
    26-Jul-2020 23:06:26.362 INFO [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDirectory Deployment of web application directory [C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\webapps\manager] has finished in [63] ms
```

Then i deleted controller.frontend.CommonFilter, thought that was the issue but now, another exception:

```
    26-Jul-2020 23:27:16.303 SEVERE [http-nio-9080-exec-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [controller.frontend.HomeServlet] in context with path [/BookStoreWebsite_war_exploded] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.persistence.Persistence
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1365)
            at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1188)
            at dao.JpaDAO.<clinit>(JpaDAO.java:18)
            at controller.frontend.HomeServlet.doGet(HomeServlet.java:29)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    26-Jul-2020 23:27:16.450 SEVERE [http-nio-9080-exec-3] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [controller.frontend.HomeServlet] in context with path [/BookStoreWebsite_war_exploded] threw exception [Servlet execution threw an exception] with root cause
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class dao.BookDAO
            at controller.frontend.HomeServlet.doGet(HomeServlet.java:29)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
            at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
            at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
            at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
            at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
            at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Here is my pom.xml:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    
        <groupId>com.bookstore</groupId>
        <artifactId>BookStoreWebsite</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <build>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>8</source>
                        <target>8</target>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </build>
        <dependencies>
    
    
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
                <version>5.3.16.Final</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
                <version>6.0.0.Alpha5</version>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>mysql</groupId>
                <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
                <version>5.1.45</version>
                <scope>runtime</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
                <version>4.0.1</version>
                <scope>provided</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>jstl</groupId>
                <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
                <version>1.2</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
                <scope>compile</scope>
            </dependency>
            
        </dependencies>
    
    </project>
```

Here is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
          http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd"
             version="2.1">
    <persistence-unit name="BookStoreWebsite">
        <properties>
            <property name = "javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bookstoredb"/>
            <property name = "javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root"/>
            <property name = "javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password"/>
            <property name = "javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value = "true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value = "true" />

            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="10" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="120" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
            <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="3000" />
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Here is my directory:

[image: directory]

I tried to google it but it didn't help. I tried to force delete maven dependencies from m2 folder and reimport it but it didn't work neither.

What is my mistake? Thank you!

Comment: Check the artifact configuration, make sure all the required jars are packaged inside, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/artifacts.html. Verify that https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/persistence-api/1.0.2 is present in the final artifact that you are deploying. Am I right that it works if you build the war via Maven, put it in webapps and start Tomcat from the command line? Compare the contents of the Maven built war and what IntelliJ IDEA artifact products to find what's missing.

Comment: The code worked when it was in Eclipse IDe and i copypasted it manually to Intellij. The same code but here doesn't work. I'll check the artifacts. But how to know whether a certain artifact is in the final artifact?

Comment: Unpack it as a zip and see what jars/libraries are inside.

Comment: Thank you,theproblem has been resolved!

Comment: @JohnSmithJohn Could you post the answer as , what resolved your issue

Comment: @MPPNBD I would be happy to do so, however i have not work with JavaEE for1.5 years and i do not remember how i fixed this. Hope you will find the answer!